# Getting camera opening error with Zxing library in Sony Xperia C

Tags: android, camera, zxing

I am trying to Scan the QR code using com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN but it does not opening the camera and always responding with "Scan was Cancelled!" toast message for Sony Xperia C only.

ScanQR.java

```
ScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

  });

 }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        // Handle successful scan

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
        toast.show();

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Handle cancel
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Scan was Cancelled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
        toast.show();

    }
}
}
```

manifest.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.ScanQR"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

   </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
startActivityForResult(
                            new Intent(
                                    Emailtry.this,
                                    com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class),
                            11);